# Accessing each grandchild element in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a User Model and Subscription Model.
    The User model "hasMany" relationship with subscription as Subscription"belongsTo" User.
    In my blade I am trying somethings like this to display all the user and their subscriptions.
    Note: $users = Models\User::all()

```
 `@foreach($users as $user)
    <ul>
    User:{{$user->name}}
    @foreach($user->subscription as $sub)
    {{$sub->expiry_date}}
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach`
```

The names are displayed, but the subscriptions don't display. Any help please.

Models

```
 //The User model
Public function subscription()
{
 return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Subscription');
}


//In my Subscription Model
public function user()
{
 return $this->belongs to('\App\Models\User');
}
```

Comment: Is subscriptions table seeded? and the records linked to the user records?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Seeded and Linked.

Comment: Hmm, strange, could you add <?php dd($user->subscription); ?> after the @foreach($users as $user) in blade and post the result? Also, is the table linked by user_id in the subscriptions table?